# Nested CASE WHEN Formula comparing two Netsuite Fields (Saved Search)

Tags: netsuite, concatenation, case-when

I'm trying this formula below, I've tried using "=", "LIKE" AND "IS" but nothing works.

```
CASE 
WHEN {VENDOR} LIKE {OTHERVENDOR} THEN {VENDOR}
ELSE WHEN {VENDOR} LIKE {OTHERVENDOR} THEN {CONCAT(CONCAT({VENDOR}, ', '),{OTHERVENDOR}) 
END
```

If the Vendor is A and the Item has no other Vendor then I just want to show what the Preferred is i.e. A.

If the Vendor is A and has B, C & D then I want to display it as A, B, C & D.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple vendors set up?

This works in my account on a Formula(Text) column on an item search:

```
case when {othervendor} = {vendor} then {vendor} else {vendor} || ', ' || {othervendor} end
```

Comment: That works Fine! 
However just thought of something, this still provides duplicate Internal IDs. I wouldn't be able to do this in Excel as Excel would remove the First Line in said duplicate and that won't always be correct. Any thoughts how I can get those out. 

I'm going to try Max and see what happens. 
 
Also, Some items might have 2 or 3 vendors as sometimes we might find someone who provides the exact item but it's cheaper, and IF that vendor in the future cannot provide the item then we can fall back on the previous vendor, but we will always have 1 preferred.

Comment: Yeah, I've 'Grouped' the Internal ID and used the 'Max' function on the Formula, and works fine. Thank you.